# GCC not complaining about array out of bounds

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, valgrind

Surely there is something wrong with this right?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM 1
#define NUM_SWARMS 3

typedef float coor_t[NUM];
typedef coor_t gBestX_t[NUM_SWARMS];

gBestX_t gBestX;

int main()
{
  gBestX[0][1] = 3.0;
  gBestX[1][1] = 3.0;
  gBestX[8][1] = 4.0;

  printf("%f\n", gBestX[8][1]);

  return 0;
}
```

In my mind this is creating gBestX as a 2D array of size [1][3] but yet gcc nor valgrind is complaining about this and I get the correct output (4.0). Is this not a violation of an array out of bounds?

Comment: Yes it is. But why do you expect gcc to complain about it? (And I think valgrind only checks malloc'ed memory, not global or local variables)

Comment: @immibis I guess I thought gcc would complain about access memory outside of the bounds of the array.

Comment: @immibis Is there a flag or a better way to do this so that if I screw up in my program it will bring it up as a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc only warns about bounds if you enable that warning. See [gcc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) man page for more details:

```
   -Warray-bounds
   -Warray-bounds=n
       This option is only active when -ftree-vrp is active (default for -O2 and above). It warns about
       subscripts to arrays that are always out of bounds. This warning is enabled by -Wall.

       -Warray-bounds=1
           This is the warning level of -Warray-bounds and is enabled by -Wall; higher levels are not, and must
           be explicitly requested.

       -Warray-bounds=2
           This warning level also warns about out of bounds access for arrays at the end of a struct and for
           arrays accessed through pointers. This warning level may give a larger number of false positives and
           is deactivated by default.
```

Comment: I'm using -Wall and get nothing. I now tried -Warray-bounds=2 and still get no warnings.

Comment: Oh ok, when I add the -O2 flag it gives the warning. Thanks.

Comment: I should also note that with -ftree-vrp and without -O2 my problem still persisted.

Comment: @wuttadowner Note: gcc won't *always* be able to notice out-of-bounds array acccesses, only some of the time.

Comment: @immibis Would this happen often? Or in special cases?

Comment: @wuttadowner Often enough that you shouldn't expect gcc to notice all out-of-bounds accesses. This particular case is probably easy for it, since the array indices are constants. But imagine if you had something like `scanf("%d", &index); printf("%d", array[index]);`

Answer (score 0):

You need a newer gcc.  I get warnings when I compile:

Bruces-MacBook-Pro:test bruce$ gcc -o t15 t15.c
t15.c:13:4: warning: array index 1 is past the end of the array (which contains 1 element) [-Warray-bounds]
          gBestX[0][1] = 3.0;
          ^         ~
t15.c:9:1: note: array 'gBestX' declared here
gBestX_t gBestX;
^
t15.c:14:6: warning: array index 1 is past the end of the array (which contains 1 element) [-Warray-bounds]
            gBestX[1][1] = 3.0;
            ^         ~
t15.c:9:1: note: array 'gBestX' declared here
gBestX_t gBestX;
^
t15.c:15:8: warning: array index 1 is past the end of the array (which contains 1 element) [-Warray-bounds]
              gBestX[8][1] = 4.0;
              ^         ~
t15.c:9:1: note: array 'gBestX' declared here
gBestX_t gBestX;
^
t15.c:17:25: warning: array index 1 is past the end of the array (which contains 1 element) [-Warray-bounds]
                printf("%f\n", gBestX[8][1]);
                               ^         ~
t15.c:9:1: note: array 'gBestX' declared here
gBestX_t gBestX;
^
4 warnings generated.

Comment: I have version 5.2.0.

Comment: Yup, just got it. Had to add -O2 with -Wall or -Warray-bounds to get the warning. See my comment under Pauli Nieminen's answer. Thanks.